# using s3 copy failed with access denied

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to copy a file from one folder in s3 bucket to another folder. I am using aws jdk to copy the file.I checked other questions, but mostly it is using other sdk's. I have used the same way mentioned in this post([AWS S3 copy object source key and destination key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33782740/aws-s3-copy-object-source-key-and-destination-key?rq=1)) only different my key contains folder structure.

I am using the below code.

```
public CopyObjectResult copyToAFolder(String sourceBucketName,
        String sourceKeyName, String destinationBucketName,
        String destinationKeyName) {
    LOG.info(
            "Archiving the file Source:{},SourceKey:{},Destination:{},DestinationKey:{}",
            new Object[] { sourceBucketName, sourceKeyName, destinationBucketName,
                    destinationKeyName });
    CopyObjectRequest copyObjRequest = new CopyObjectRequest(sourceBucketName,
            sourceKeyName, destinationBucketName, destinationKeyName);
    return amazonS3Client.copyObject(copyObjRequest);
}
```

I am passing the parameter like this.I got the key name by using listing service, so the key name is right.

```
 sourceBucketName: myTestBucket
 sourceKeyName:testing/movement/sample.txt
 destinationBucketName:myTestBucket
 destinationKeyName:testing/movement2/sample.txt(I have tried with /testing/movement2/ also)
```

This fails with accessDenied exception. I have full access to this bucket, I am able to delete files from this bucket using S3Client. The access denied is specific to copy alone. Any idea why this would happen.

Error.

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: XXXXXXXXXXXX)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1343) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.37.jar:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:961) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.37.jar:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:738) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.37.jar:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:489) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.37.jar:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:448) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.37.jar:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:397) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.37.jar:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:378) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.37.jar:na]
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4039) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.37.jar:na]
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.copyObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1714) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.37.jar:na]
```

Comment: did you check the file has the permission, file may have its own permission in addition to the bucket

Comment: It has permission, I am able to delete this file.

Comment: are you making request as IAM user, AWS checks permission on different contexts http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-auth-workflow-object-operation.html

Comment: Where are you running this code? On an EC2 instance with a role assigned? Or from your local computer? The main question is how the code is obtaining credentials and whether those credentials have permissions on *both* buckets. Try copying to a different path within the *same* bucket as a test to check the credentials. You could even try a `ListObjects` call to see whether you have appropriate bucket access.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where I was getting access denied..

Turned out it was because I wasn't copying the object with metadata and thus adding an encryption algorithm.

```
    ObjectMetadata metadatum = new ObjectMetadata();
    metadatum.setSSEAlgorithm(AES);
    request.setNewObjectMetadata(metadatum);
```

Answer (score -1):

The Solution can be,

- You need to mention correct AWS S3 Endpoint in Java Code.
- Try it in Internet Explorer than Chrome. Because Chrome only takes filename not whole file path.
- If you are trying to access S3 from EC2 instance then instance should have S3 IAM role with necessary permission.
- If you are working in local computer then make sure both Access key and Secret Access key are correct and valid.

Thanks.